# federated login for google account users in packaged chrome app

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, google-openid

I want to implement federated login for google account users in my packaged chrome app. In the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID#settingup) is written that I should use

> OpenID 2.0-compliant library compatible with your programming
>   language.

Which library should I use if I have javascript code? There is no javascript library so I have no idea how to include a library to my app. Any suggestions?

maybe someone know links to the working examples? I'm really confused about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all information about OAuth in chrome extensions [here](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_oauth.html) (with examples)

I think that it is same for app and extension.

Hope this will help you